# The uniqueness of the Gamma Function

Tags: real-analysis, special-functions, gamma-function

It is a theorem that any function $f$ defined for positive real numbers satisfying

1. $f(1)=1$
2. $f(x+1)=x\cdot f(x)$
3. $f$ is log convex

is identically equal to the gamma function. (Condition 2 means that this function interpolates a shifted factorial function.)

Now, a beginner (such as myself) might ask: **What if we weaken condition 2 by instead requiring $f$ to be merely convex, not log convex?**

I would imagine that such functions would look not too different, since intuitively, I can't wildly deviate the graph of the gamma function if I want to maintain condition 2 and stay convex.

Just a follow-up musing---What if instead of condition 3, we require convexity and infinite differentiability? Do we still uniquely determine the gamma function?

Comment: See [this](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/why-is-eulers-gamma-function-the-best-extension-of-the-factorial-function-to-t).

Comment: For completeness, this is the [Bohr–Mollerup theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr–Mollerup_theorem).

Comment: Artin's book *The Gamma Function* contains some other results on uniqueness that depend on continuity or continuous differentiability only but require Legendre functional equation.

Comment: See also http://mathoverflow.net/questions/23229/importance-of-log-convexity-of-the-gamma-function .

Answer (score 1):

(This should be either a comment or CW.)

Peter Luschny [studied](http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunctionMJ.html) a number of gamma-like functions that do not have the log-convex imposition; you might want to look into them for inspiration.

Comment: I do not think Luschny's examples satisfy condition 2. Any functions satisfying 1 and 2 must have a singularity at the origin.