# Is there a Smooth, convex alternative to the Gamma fucntion.

Tags: functions, gamma-function, smooth-functions

Is the a function $f(x)$ other then the Gamma function with said properties.

1. $f(x)=(x-1)!$ when x is a non-negative integer.
2. $f(x)$ is smooth (infinitely differentiable.)
3. $f(x)$ is convex.
4. $f(x)=xf(x-1)$. for x>1

I know that the Gamma function is the only solution if 3. is strengthened to being Logarithmically convex.

Comment: A related question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/26680/the-uniqueness-of-the-gamma-function

Comment: I'm requiring the function to be Smooth.

Comment: You may want to know that if you strengthen the conditions to $\log \circ f$ being convex and $f$ being analytic there is only one such function. See [Bohr-Mallerup Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem)

Comment: Aren't you nailing the function you need pretty much to the Gamma function by setting those properties? And could you not differentiate the Gamma function (in the positive Real)  by multiplying the digamma by the gamma? (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kjK9WfmLElo) - What do you plan on using the function you are looking for for?

Comment: If I weaken 2 to simply be Continuous differentiable I can come up with other functions. $y=0.5((xmod(1)-0.5)^2+1.75)∏max(x-i,1)$ from i=0 to i=infinity

Answer (score 0):

You might try [Hadamard's gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hadamard%27s_gamma_function)? 
$$
H(x) = \frac{1}{\Gamma (1-x)}\,\dfrac{d}{dx} \left \{ \ln \left ( \frac{\Gamma ( \frac{1}{2}-\frac{x}{2})}{\Gamma (1-\frac{x}{2})}\right ) \right \}
$$
This looks reasonably smooth and convex (not sure about the bump and have no proof of this). But.. it only satisfies your functional relationship for positive integers $x$ and is otherwise 
$$
H(x+1) = xH(x) + \frac{1}{\Gamma(1-x)}
$$
all credit to Wikipedia.

Comment: The  f(x)=xf(x-1) Property is pretty important here.

Comment: Is there an integral representation of the H gamma function @Benedict ? I couldn't find it on Wikipedia