# Uniqueness of inverse integer Mellin transforms

Tags: analytic-number-theory, z-transform, inverse-problems, mellin-transform

Let f(t) and g(t) be two real-valued integrable functions defined on the real axis $[0, \infty)$. Define the integer Mellin moments of these two functions as
\begin{equation}
F(n) = \int_0^\infty dt \,f(t) \, t^{n-1}
\end{equation}
and
\begin{equation}
G(n) = \int_0^\infty dt \,g(t) \, t^{n-1},
\end{equation}
for $n$ a non-negative integer, respectively. Suppose that these integrals exist for all $n$, i.e. converge absolutely for any $n$. Further suppose that we have no knowledge of the properties of $f(t)$, $g(t)$ other than they are real-valued, or of the Mellin transforms for non-integer $n$.

Given only that $F(n)= G(n)$ **for all n**, can we conclude that $f(t)=g(t)$? Or, rather, what can we conclude about $f(t)$ and $g(t)$? What are the restrictions on $f(t)$ and $g(t)$, if any, to have $f(t)=g(t)$?

This is related to an old question here: [Explicitly reconstructing a function from its moments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/32692/explicitly-reconstructing-a-function-from-its-moments)
but it does not seem to me that this was ever satisfactorily answered.

Edit: One plausible answer is the following:

Since $F(n) = G(n)$ for all $n$, we know that
\begin{equation}
\int_0^\infty dt \,f(t) \, t^{n-1} - \int_0^\infty dt \,g(t) \, t^{n-1} = 
\int_0^\infty dt \,(f(t)-g(t)) \, t^{n-1} = 0.
\end{equation}
This holds for all $n$, so we must have $(f(t)-g(t))=0$.

Answer (score 1):

In general, this is not unique. What you are asking about is the moment problem, and it is well-known that without additional conditions on $f$, uniqueness may not hold. Plenty of counterexamples to uniqueness can be found [here](https://books.google.com/books?id=xaH8AQAAQBAJ&lpg=PA114&ots=etdN_a7h5R&dq=counterexamples%20in%20probability%20moments&pg=PA108#v=onepage&q&f=false).

Comment: Thank you. I don't have sufficient reputation for my upvote to be displayed.