# Why do many calculators evaluate $(-0.5)!$ to $\sqrt\pi$?

Tags: factorial, pi

According to Wikipedia, factorial only is defined for non-negative integers.
How come Spotlight, the Windows calculator and the Google search engine come up with $\sqrt\pi$ if you try to solve $(-0.5)!$ ?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Extension_of_factorial_to_non-integer_values_of_argument

Comment: [Because](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia:Reference_desk/Archives/Mathematics/2013_May_7#Linking_Factorials_to_Geometric_Shapes).

Comment: What on Earth does "solve a number" mean?

Comment: @Ruslan, in this case, apparently it's meant to mean "evaluate". Not everyone is a careful with mathematical terms as they might be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The ordinary factorial function can be extended, in an essentially unique way, to a function defined everywhere except at negative integers.  This extension preserves the important $f(x+1) = (x+1)f(x)$ relation that characterizes the factorial.  (See [Extension of factorial to non-integer values](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factorial#Extension_of_factorial_to_non-integer_values_of_argument) for details.)

This extended function is defined at $-\frac12$, and its value there is $\sqrt\pi$.

Comment: It can be extended in infinite ways with functions that evaluate to $n!$ for natural $n$. The commonest/most useful one is the $\Gamma$ function. See also question [1537](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/why-is-eulers-gamma-function-the-best-extension-of-the-factorial-function-to) here.

Comment: The $\Gamma$ function is the only such extension that is log-convex, but I thought OP might not care about that, so I left it out, since it's mentioned in the page I linked.

Comment: The log-convex property is important for the factorial because it essentially means it's the least "wavy" version of the factorial.  x! is approximately x^x as x → ∞.  More precisely, it's approximately x^x*e^-x*√(2πx).  If you evaluate the graph of x!/(that asymptotic expression) as x → ∞, you'd basically just see the graph y=1.  However, if you were to do the same, but using literally any other definition of the factorial, you'd see a wavy graph, periodically bouncing above and below the line y=1 ad infinitum.  In other words, this definition of x! has the least residue.

Answer (score 2):

Hint: $\Gamma(n)=(n-1)!= \int_0^\infty x^{n-1}e^{-x}\, \mathrm{d}x$ so $(-0.5)!=(0.5-1)!=\Gamma(0.5)=\int_0^\infty x^{-0.5}e^{-x}\, \mathrm{d}x=\int_0^\infty \frac{1}{\sqrt x}e^{-x}\, \mathrm{d}x$ now you should just prove the above value equals to $\sqrt \pi$. By the way, it's better to use the term "evaluate" or "calculate" instead of "solve", because we can't actually "solve" a number!

Comment: To be honest, I wouldn't use the integral representation of the gamma function to evaluate it at $z=0.5$.

Comment: @SimplyBeautifulArt I would, to be honest. It gives an intuitive look into it. When you perform the right substitutions, you get the area under the curve of e^-x². Which is essentially a scaled version of the bell curve. After that, we can take a detour to find the volume of the graph e^(-x²-y²), which is essentially a 3D bell curve. If evaluated with rectangular coordinates, you get the square of the aforementioned area, i.e. Γ(1/2)². If evaluated with polar coordinates, however, we get π. Since the area of the scaled bell curve must be positive, this proves that Γ(1/2) has to be √(π). QED