# What does the factorial of a negative number signify?

Tags: permutations, factorial, gamma-function

I understand that the factorial gives the number of arrangements. For example: the factorial of zero i.e. an empty set ( doesn't occur) is 1.

As the empty set can be arranged only in 1 way - i.e. by filling nothing. Now, let's take an example: 5 distinct seats. How many ways 5 distinct seats can be arranged? - 5! ways i.e. 120.

So, basically, factorial gives us the arrangements. Now, the question is why do we need to know the factorial of a negative number?, let's say -5. How can we imagine that there are -5 seats, and we need to arrange it? Something, which doesn't exist shouldn't have an arrangement right? Can someone please throw some light on it?. I saw some research done on the formula - https://mathoverflow.net/questions/10124/the-factorial-of-1-2-3

Comment: Luckily we do not need any interpretation in reality for mathematical concepts. If there is one - as for $n!$ where $n$ is a nonnegative integer - then that is nice, but we can do without. That is one of the things I like in mathematics. We can go on as far as we want :).

Comment: See answer here: http://math.stackexchange.com/a/839718/131263

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The factorials of negative *integers* have no defined meaning.

Reason: We know that factorials satisfy $x\cdot(x-1)!=x!$. However, if there was a $(-1)!$, then we'd be able to write:
\begin{align}
x\cdot(x-1)!&=x!\\
0\cdot(-1)!&=0!\\
0&=1
\end{align}
Contradiction.

However, there *is* a meaningful definition of the factorials of *non-integers*! [Here is a graph](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/73/Generalized_factorial_function.svg). One motivation for this particular way of doing it is, they wanted these two properties to hold (even when $x,t$ are not integers):

- $x\cdot(x-1)!=x!$ for all $x$ (as long as $(x-1)!$ exists)
- $(n+t)!\approx n!\,n^t$ (when $n$ is large)

Comment: Wow, this confuses me more. Why do we need to look at the previous state? The -t state. What happened in the past is of no use to us. The reference should be zero always.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean. (Also: made a slight edit.)

Comment: Could the downvoter please explain?

Answer (score 3):

As Akiva Weinberger states, the factorial of a negative integer is undefined, however, there are some nifty ways we can get around to negative non-integers... though they don't represent much to my knowledge.

First notice that for positive whole numbers, we have

$$\frac{n!(n+1)^m}{(n+m)!}=\frac{(n+1)^m}{(n+1)\dots(n+m)}=\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^m}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)\dots\left(1+\frac mn\right)}$$

The first step follows by expanding the factorials and cancelling like factors.  Then divide the entire fraction by $n^m/n^m$ to get the second step.

As $n$ tends to become infinitely large, then for any $m$, we get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!(n+1)^m}{(n+m)!}=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\left(1+\frac1n\right)^m}{\left(1+\frac1n\right)\dots\left(1+\frac mn\right)}=\frac{(1+0)^m}{(1+0)\dots(1+0)}=1$$

Where we make use of the fact that $1/\infty=0$ (to be quick and hand-wavy)

Assuming this property holds for non-whole numbers $m$, we now state that the limit

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!(n+1)^m}{(n+m)!}=1$$

We now let non-whole number $x$ take the place of $m$,

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!(n+1)^x}{(n+x)!}=1$$

Multiply both sides by $x!$ to get

$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!x!(n+1)^x}{(n+x)!}=x!$$

Notice that in the same fashion of expanding the factorials (assuming non-integer factorials behave like they normally would), we may find that

$$\frac{x!}{(n+x)!}=\frac1{(x+1)\dots(x+n)}$$

And thus,

> $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!(n+1)^x}{(x+1)\dots(x+n)}=x!$$

WHOA WHOA WHOA!  HOLD UP!  Do you see what I see?

$$\begin{array}{c|c|c}&\text{makes sense}&\text{makes no sense}\\\hline n!&\color{green}\checkmark\\(n+1)^x&\color{green}\checkmark\\(x+1)\dots(x+n)&\color{green}\checkmark\\x!&&\color{green}\checkmark\end{array}$$

*ahem* so the only thing we don't yet understand is a non-integer factorial, that is, $x!$, but everything else makes sense... so why not use this for non-integer factorials?

$$x!=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!(n+1)^x}{(x+1)\dots(x+n)}$$

Hm... there was an oddity here though... look what happens at a negative integer:

$$(-1)!=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!(n+1)^{-1}}{\color{red}{(-1+1)}\dots(-1+n)}$$

Ah... so negative integers result in division by zero.  Go figure if you read Akiva Weinberger's answer.  But we can do some fun stuff with this, like...

$$(1/2)!=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!\sqrt{n+1}}{\left(\frac12+1\right)\dots\left(\frac12+n\right)}$$

And if you [take a look at this graph](https://www.desmos.com/calculator/ynrw9iyk0a), you will see that

$$(1/2)!=\frac{\sqrt\pi}2$$

This extends beyond negative numbers as well.  Indeed, you could even take complex numbers into the scheme:

$$i!=\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!(n+1)^i}{(i+1)\dots(i+n)}$$

Other forms of the extended factorial (Gamma function) may be found on Wikipedia:

[Gamma function
From Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function)

Answer (score -1):

А почему бы не поступить намного проще? Тем же самым, "аналитическим продолжением". Только, продолжим положительные значения факториала, на отрицательные значения n, через модуль n, и ещё сделаем функцию нечётной: (-n)!=-(|n|!). Можно для этой операции воспользоваться функцией y=sign(x). Прежде всего, далее будем работать с натуральными логарифмами факториалов. y(x)=(sign(x)*ln(|x|!)). Полученная нами функция очень напоминает кубическую параболу. Вот ею мы и аппроксимируем набор целочисленных значений факториалов. Зададим кубический сплайн, в виде z(x)=A(x)*ln(|(x-1)*x*(x+1)|), чтобы иметь три, строго заданных, корня z1={-1;0}, z2={0;0}, z3={1;0}. А параметрическую функцию A(x), подберём, методом наименьших квадратов. Так, чтобы не было более паразитных корней, других корней, кроме z1, z2, z3. И для этого, хорошо подойдут параболы чётных степеней, начиная со второй степени, вида A(x)=a*x^2+b*x+c. Приближать регрессионную модель будем, как отношение логарифма факториала, к логарифму сплайна. То есть, выражение вида A(x)=(sign(x)*ln(|x|!))/ln(|(x-1)*x*(x+1)|). И нам не надо знать точно аналитическое выражение для A(x), поскольку, на практике, все расчёты, всё равно, ведутся на компьютере, на ограниченном множестве значений, с ограниченной разрядностью, и ограниченной точностью вычислений. А теперь, в чём смысл такой подгонки, зачем нам всё это надо? Если понимать отрицательные числа, как "долги по кредитам", а факториалы, как перестановки без повторений, то не важно, в каком порядке выбирать долги для их уплаты. Поэтому, факториалы сохранят прежний положительный смысл. Но зачем нам нужна нечётность факториала в отрицательной области? А это, для расчёта мультиномиального коэффициента, выражающее число перестановок с повторением P=n!/(k1!*k2!*...kn!), или это коэффициенты сочетаний C(k_i,n), в полиноме Гаврилова (x1+x2+...xn)^n (это общение бинома Ньютона (x1+x2)^n). В числителе P, положительные и отрицательные значения аргументов факториалов произведут арифметическое сокращение (k1-k2+k3-...+kn)!, и числитель n! может от этого сильно уменьшиться, прежде, чем от него будет взят факториал. Физический смысл такого коэффициента, может быть понят из формулы Больцмана для энтропии S=k*ln(W), и формулы энтропии по Хартли в информатике H=ln(N). Отрицательная энтропия может трактоваться, как "негэнтропия". Итак, что Вы по поводу все го этого думаете? СтОит ли так упрощать?  Далее идёт машинный перевод с русского на английский, поэтому возможны неточности перевода. Благодарю за внимание. Ян Корчмарюк, к.т.н., Россия, Волгоград, 2022 г.