# prove $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \binom{k}{n} $ converges absolutely

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence, summation, infinity

> Show that for $k>0$, the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty } \binom{k}{n} $ converges absolutely

It is clearly that as $n\longrightarrow \infty $, it will be greater than k eventually. That's my problem, I don't know anything about the combination function with the lower variable bigger than the upper. In order to solve this problem, is there any similar subject or question around here? Could someone point out for me please? Thanks a lot!

Comment: "I don't know anything about the combination function with the lower variable bigger than the upper." So just to search and learn it...

Comment: As MathFail mentioned, [the wiki entry should be of use to you.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)

Comment: Note that $\binom{k}{n} = \frac{k(k-1)...(k-(n-1))}{n!}$

Comment: ${k \choose n} =0$ when $n > k$, $k\in \mathbb{Z}$ .

Comment: @vertex: Only if $k$ is an integer.

Comment: @MartinR fixed.

Comment: @MathFail roger that!

Comment: @MathFail, we all must do our part here, be it searching or reading community guidelines as Shaun [advised](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4714356/721644) you.

Comment: @mlrofcloud. Did I answer your question?

Comment: All the terms are positive, so absolute convergence is the same as ordinary convergence.

Answer (score 2):

For $n\in\mathbb{N}$ and $n>k>0$,
$$\begin{align*} 
\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|&=\left|\frac{\binom{k}{n}}{\binom{k}{n+1}}\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{k!}{n!(k-n)!}\frac{(n+1)!(k-n-1)!}{k!}\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{(n+1)!}{n!}\frac{(k-n-1)!}{(k-n)!}\right| \\
&=\left|\frac{n+1}{k-n}\right| \\
&=\frac{n+1}{n-k}
\end{align*}$$
then by [Raabe's test](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/RaabesTest.html),
$$\begin{align*}
\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left[n\left(\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}-1\right)\right]&=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left[n\left(\frac{n+1}{n-k}-1\right)\right] \\
&=\lim_{n\to+\infty}\left[\frac{n(1+k)}{n-k}\right] \\
&=1+k>1
\end{align*}$$
the series is absolutely convergent.

Comment: To answer your minor question about the [Binomial Coefficient](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/BinomialCoefficient.html) for $n>k$, [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2620397/what-happens-when-in-a-combination-n-choose-k-n-k-is-this-0?noredirect=1) should help.

Comment: Sir, can we just .........(1)ignore the fact that as $n⟶\infty$ it will be greater than k eventually and (2)treat $k$ as some integer regardless that it actually for any $k>0$.........  so that then use the formula of combination directly like you performed?

Answer (score 1):

If $k$ is an integer, $\binom kn=0$ for every $n>k$ so the series is a finite sum.

Assume now $N<k<N+1$ for some integer $N$ and let $A:=k(k-1)\dots(k-N).$ Then, for every $n>N,$
$$\left|\binom kn\right|=A\,\frac{(N+1-k)(N+2-k)\dots(n-1-k)}{n!}=B\,\frac{\Gamma(n-k)}{n!}$$
with $B:=\frac A{\Gamma(N+1-k)}.$ By [Stirling's formulae](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation), as $n\to\infty,$
$$\left|\binom kn\right|\sim B\frac{\sqrt{\frac{2\pi}{n-k}}\left(\frac{n-k}e\right)^{n-k}}{\sqrt{2\pi n}\left(\frac ne\right)^n}\sim\frac Bn\left(\frac ne\right)^{-k}\left(1-\frac kn\right)^n\sim\frac B{n^{1+k}},$$
whence the convergence, since $1+k>1.$