# Solutions $(x, y),\;x,y\in \mathbb Z$ to the equation $x! +1 = y^2$

Tags: factorial, natural-numbers

Solve
$x! +1 = y^2$ over integers.

I don't know what to try here. The equation implies that $x! = (y-1)(y+1)$ but I'm not sure if that helps at all.

Comment: $x=4$, $y=5$ works.  ($4! + 1 = 25 = 5^2$).  Just an example.  Also, $x= 5!, y= 11$ Works.  $5!+1 = 121= 11^2$.

Comment: Oops, in the second example, I meant $x= 5, y=11$.

Comment: The Question as it relates to *nonnegative* integers (note $x\in \mathbb N$ implies $x!+1$ is positive) is known as Brocard's problem. Any solution $(x,y)$ in that context gives rise to the corresponding solution $(x,-y)$.  The only further possibility would involve *negative* integers $x$.  But the factorial function $x!$ does not give an integer result for negative integers $x$, as the [gamma function](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/927382/what-does-the-factorial-of-a-negative-number-signify) has analytic poles there.

Answer (score 4):

The three known solutions $(x,y)$ to [Brocard's problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brocard%27s_problem) are $(x,y)=(4,5)$, $(x,y)=(5,11)$, and $(x,y)=(7,71)$.

Comment: Sort of a "link only" answer (though I had to provide the link).  Please explain (summarize)  why no further solutions have been known.

Comment: Considering "Paul Erdős conjectured that no other solutions exist. Overholt (1993) showed that there are only finitely many solutions provided that the abc conjecture is true. Berndt & Galway (2000) performed calculations for n up to 109 and found no further solutions. Matson (2017) has recently claimed to have extended this by 3 orders of magnitude to one trillion" I'd say "Please explain (summarize) why no further solutions have been known" is a bit of an unrealistic request.

Comment: Thanks , I didn't know this was an unsolved problem. It's in a math magazine with olympiad problems.