# Can you generalise the Gamma function?

Tags: complex-analysis, gamma-function

The Gamma function is a meromorphic function such that
\begin{equation}
  \Gamma(z+1) = z\, \Gamma(z), \quad \Gamma(1) = 1. 
\end{equation}
The [Bohr–Mollerup theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr%E2%80%93Mollerup_theorem) states that the Gamma function is the *unique* solution to this functional equation, under the condition that $ \log \Gamma(x) $ be convex on the positive reals.

Let $f$ be an entire function.

- Under what conditions on $f$ does there exist a meromorphic function $G$ such that
  $$ G(z+1) = f(z)\, G(z), \quad G(1) = 1? $$
- Under what conditions does a unique solution exist?
- Are there any such 'generalised Gamma functions' that have standardised names?

Comment: Did you try to google for generalized Gamma functions (if not, why not?)? I found [this article](https://arxiv.org/abs/1105.6002), and many more. Also MSE has some related questions, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537/why-is-eulers-gamma-function-the-best-extension-of-the-factorial-function-to).

Comment: http://www.luschny.de/math/factorial/hadamard/HadamardsGammaFunctionMJ.html

Comment: Have you seen the Barnes G function? This is the special case of $f(z)=\Gamma(z)$.