# Where does the gamma function come from

Tags: gamma-function

It has long been known that the gamma function is an extension (shift) of the factorial function defined on integers.

There were an infinite numbers of ways to continue the factorial, so what property does the gamma function have that makes/made us use it? (Also, this question is not about history, but the unique features of a gamma function.)

Comment: Have you done any research on this question, such as reading about the [motivation for this definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function#Motivation)?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bohr-Mollerup_theorem

Comment: A good reference is Emil Artin's book "The Gamma Function" I think.

Comment: Possible duplicate of a [highly voted (and older) post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1537) also tells you why Gamma is the "best" extension.

Comment: Once $f(s) =C+ \sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{1}{s+n}- \frac{1}{n+1}$ converges and is analytic away from negative integers then it is clear that $f(s+1) = f(s)+\frac1s$. Letting $ F(s) = 1+\int_1^s f(z)dz $ and choosing $C$ such that $F(1) = F(2)$ then it is clear that $ F(s+1) = F(s)+ \log s, e^{F(s+1)}= s e^{F(s)}, e^{F(n+1)}= n!$. From there, the impressive and non-trivial fact is that $e^{F(s)} = \int_0^\infty t^{s-1} e^{-t}dt$.

Comment: Read [this](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2309786?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)